# docker pull image policy/settings

Tags: docker

My situation is I have two images with the same tag(hash different), one at local and another at the registry. When I build dockerfile, docker always compares the hash of the two images find not equal then will pull the registry one.
I know there has an `imagePullPolicy` in k8s. My question is docker has any settings like `imagePullPolicy`?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: As far as I know, you'd always need to always pull the latest version of the remote tag first before building

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Docker tooling by and large either assumes you're going to manually pull images, or provides a `--pull` option to integrate it with other commands.  For example:

- [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) has a `--pull` option to try to retrieve a newer version of `FROM` images
- [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) does not; it will always reuse the image you already have, or pull one if you don't have it
- Neither core [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/) nor [`docker-compose up`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) has a `--pull` option, but there is a [`docker-compose pull`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/pull/) command that pulls every image listed in a `docker-compose.yml` file
- [`docker-compose build`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/build/) does have a `--pull` option

Core Docker always tries to pull an image if it is not present; there is no equivalent to `imagePullPolicy: Never`.  Conversely, it never tries to communicate with an image registry outside of an explicit "pull" operation; you also cannot make `docker run` act like `imagePullPolicy: Always`.

It's good practice in Kubernetes to use a unique tag per build, so you can specify an explicit build and don't have to worry about `imagePullPolicy`.  If you do this, in plain Docker, the implicit "pull if missing" will get you the correct behavior as well.

Comment: It appears that `docker-compose up` now offers a `--pull` flag. See the [`docker-compose up` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_up/) under the "Options" table.

Answer (score 1):

As a potential addendum to @David Maze's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64499580/4763116), it looks like `docker run` now also has a `--pull` [option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#-set-the-pull-policy---pull).